# Comapring data sets in two delimited files

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two tab delimited files, of 3 columns and n number of rows.

I would like print only those **rows** which are non overlapping in the two files. I am using Shell scripting.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
`diff -b file1 file2` ?
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the file in which this row is present? I mean like value x  and file 2, value y file 1

Answer (score 3):

`comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

The `-3` option will suppress any lines that are common between file1 and file2.